# MATLAB: count number of peaks

Tags: matlab

I have a graph like this and I want to determine the number of peaks. Since it's a wave function the whole graph has many peaks that is why I was unsuccefull in finding the number of peaks using functions such as `findpeaks` for the graph below it returns a number of peaks around 3000 whereas I want to have the number 7. 
[image]

My idea was to do a for or while loop that counts the number of instances where the average is higher than 0.5. So ultimately I want a function that iterates in segments over the graph returns the number of peaks and the range of y index values for which this peak occurs (I think the best way to do this would to save them to a zeros matrix).

link of file data: https://www.dropbox.com/s/vv8vqv28mqzfr9l/Example_data.mat?dl=0

Comment: You probably want to run this through a low pass filter before finding your peaks if you only want those 7 "thick" peaks

Comment: Can you join the .mat file ? It's more convenient when we can try differents solutions by ourself.

Comment: @Dan I looked into the low pass filter. However since I'm not an advanced MatLab user I probably want to go for something simpler.

Comment: @Flo then you probably need to find simpler data that have already been cleaned up for you. Filtering this data is as easy as calling `conv(data, ones(n,1)/n,'same')`

Comment: Please don't vandalize your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean you are trying to count the 'on' parts of your data?

You're on the right track using `findpeaks`. If you scroll to the bottom of the [documentation](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/findpeaks.html) you'll see that you can actually tweak the routine in various ways, for example specifying the minimum distance between peaks, or the minimum difference between a point and its neighbour before it is considered a peak.

By defining the minimum distance between peaks, I detected the following 7 peaks. Code is included below. Alternatively you can play around with the other parameters you can pass into `findpeaks`.

The only other thing to note is that I took the absolute value of your data.

[image: Peaks]

```
load('Example_data.mat')
indx = 1:numel(number11);
[pks, locs] = findpeaks(abs(number11), indx, 'MinPeakDistance', 0.25e4);
hold on
plot(number11)
plot(locs,pks, 'rx')
disp(numel(pks))
```

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I needed. For the second part of my question, could you give me an idea to get (roughly) the index of the values for which these peaks occur? I thought to have a (number of peaks)*2 matrix (in this case a 7*2) and in the first column the (approximate) start of peak i and the second column the end index. As I said it does not have to be very precise as it is real-life data.

Comment: The approximate indices for which these peaks occur is given in `locs` above. If you actually want the start point and the end point of the various 'on' periods I think you would have to take a completely different approach. Maybe take a moving average using `smooth` and determine the 'on' and 'off' points to correspond to points where the moving average crosses a threshold.